# FInd nearest value within list condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, conditional-statements

I want to find nearest value of a cell but don't know how.

[image: Screenshot may help you to understand the question]

In my excel sheet cell B1 has a value(LIST NAME) and cell B2 has other value which is to be searched with condition. If cell B1 has value GP_42(list name) then search the value of cell B2 withing list GP_42 (D4:D13) If cell B1 has value GP_42(list name) then se[![enter image description here][2]][2]arch the value of cell B2 withing list GP_42 (E4:E13). If value doesn't match then result should be the nearest matched value. Result should be display in the cell B3.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the closest value above, or below, your search value? Say in `GP_42` you have `36200` and `36400`. Which one do you want as the "Result Value"?

Comment: Yes, I want closest value but from the Lists. If cell B1 has value GP_42 then select closest value of cell B2 from the list GP_42 (cell reference D3:D12) or if cell B1 has value GP_46 then select from the list GP_46 (cell reference E3:E12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you want the closest value. This means that you need the *absolute* ([ABS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ABS-function-3420200F-5628-4E8C-99DA-C99D7C87713C)) of the difference between the value in GP_42 and your search value.

In B3 as an **array formula**¹,

```
=INDEX(GP_42, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(GP_42)/(ABS(GP_42-B$2)=MIN(ABS(GP_42-B$2))), ROW(1:1))-ROW(GP_42)+1)
```

I have used `ROW(1:1)` to represent the number 1. This gives you the first encountered match. In my expanded examples, the third has two matches that meet the 'minimum difference' in B9 and B10. B10 is achieved by filling down. This advances `ROW(1:1)` to `ROW(2:2)` which represents 2 and gives you the second available match.

[image]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>