# Nearest value to average

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a sample like this where I want to find nearest value to average

city and weight are two separate columns

```
city  weight
A      23
A      22
A      45
A      97
B      34
B      22
B      23
C      76
C      23
C      23
```

I made a pivot and calculated the average of weight for A- which is 46.75

I need to find nearest number for A which will be 45 in this case

I think i need to use index and match, but how would i do it if have 17,000 rows with duplicate city names and different weight values?

Any help I would appreciate

so answer i am looking for is

```
Row Labels  Average of WEIGHT     nearest number
A                 46.75            45
B                 38.75            34
C                  23              23
```

Most similar answers are not using this set, please help me set up this formula i have tried:

INDEX(rawdata,MATCH(MIN(ABS(weight-$B2)),ABS(weight-$B2),0),2)

But it look at at whole array of weight from A-C. I oonly want it to look at values for A when it is comparing average of A,

And then weight of B when comparing average of B,

AND SO ON....

Please let me know what is wrong with my formula?

thanks in advance

Comment: The avg of B is 26.333 and the avg of C is 40.667.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097187/find-nearest-value-within-list-condition/42099062#42099062

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770461/use-of-index-match-to-find-absolute-closest-value

Comment: Guys other examples are different from mine. Any help would be appreciated, i spent too many hours on it. Thanks in advance

Comment: here is what worked for me, I can't believe no one helped here, it was a different question not similar to what everyone was sending me to :=INDEX(rawdata,MATCH(SMALL(IF(combi=$A2,ABS(weight-$B2)),1),IF(combi=$A2,ABS(weight-$B2)),0),2)